# Google Tag Manager & Youtube Conflict

Tags: youtube-api, video-streaming, google-tag-manager

**EDIT:** the problem is no longer relevant.
GTM do not affect Youtube API anymore. (In the jsFiddle demo, video informations (state, currentTime, duration) are always correct).

Calling the Google Tag Manager seems to wreck the Youtube API.
Here is a fiddle demo :

[Google Tag Manager & Youtube (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/jniac/rnLmyjrq/2/)

```
// where thoses methods do not work anymore
player.getPlayerState();
player.getCurrentTime();
player.getDuration();
```

by commenting the line 16 Youtube API works again (correct state, correct currentTime / duration displayed).
Since the video is still playing, it seems like the js api is disabled.

Any idea to avoid that ?

Comment: Can you provide the error logs?

Comment: the error logs ? i do not have any.
In the link provided above (https://jsfiddle.net/jniac/rnLmyjrq/2/) when turning off the line 16 (doCallGTM();) and run again, you'll see some informations about the player (state, current time etc.) that you couldn't get previously. That's all i have...

Answer (score 0):

The GTM container you load in the fiddle has a number of heavy customizations against the YouTube API in Custom JavaScript variables. By disabling / removing those variables, the YT methods on the page should work again.

So this would be a custom scripting issue in the Custom JavaScript variables you have created in GTM, and not a native issue with GTM's built-in functionalities.