# There is no GTM.video in GTM Preview Mode

Tags: youtube-api, google-tag-manager

As Google Tag Manager released the new update for built in variables for Youtube, I followed this tutorial of Simo Ahava for Youtube tracking: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/the-youtube-video-trigger-in-google-tag-manager/

However, when I test my website in Preview mode, there is no gtm.video data layer. Because of that, there is no tag firing.

Any help will be appreciated, and if you believe my website has this video embedded code hidden, here is my page with video: https://www.magestore.com/magento-store-manager

Thank you!

Edited: Even if there is no gtm.video in Preview Mode, the tag actually still fires. You can check it in Real time mode of GA or wait until GA collects enough data.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

We are having an issue with this functionality as well. We followed Simo's blog to implement and as of yesterday the functionality has become very unstable. We maybe have the tag firing 1 out of 20 page loads. We have tried loading the iframe_api as the first script. We have changed the ordering of the scripts. Something seems wrong with the code from Google.

I should also add that's it's not just the gtm.preview but if you publish the changes you will not see gtm.video firing with any regularity.

We think that GTM and YT API don't work well together - as per this post.
[Google Tag Manager & Youtube Conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43682942/google-tag-manager-youtube-conflict)

Comment: Funny. Even without gtm.video in Preview Mode, the tag still fires and GA still has this event.